# Regular Expression for second occurrence of numbers in brackets

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that targets the second occurrence of numbers within brackets. Here's an example.

```
[123] testing [1234]
```

should select 1234.

So far I have this expression

```
^.*?\[[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*\].*$
```

but it only selects 123

How do I make it select 1234?

Thanks

Comment: The second or last occurrence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
^.*?\[\d+].*?\[(\d+)]
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iI5tM7/2)

Comment: @compsciguy.: No worries, glad I could help.

Comment: Could I bother you for one more regular expression question? I'm trying to also find the first occurrence of dates such as "10/4/2015" or "3/25/2015" or 10/12/2015 but it is hard for me to do because I also have to find dates with 1 or 2 digits for month and days. It would be great if you could find this regular expression for me.

Comment: actually i looked around and found this reg ex ^(0*[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0*[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d$ i tested it and it seems to work well.